# How to work with Sensitive (personal) Data, without actually seeing it?

Tags: dataset

I'm currently working on a project that has sensitive data. I'm allowed to see the data on a single platform (company PC), but outside of that platform I cannot process it. I'd like to train a ML algorithm with the data but to do so I'll have to use a different PC. I cannot process the data on that PC though.

Is there anyway to translate and preserve the data in a format that can still be used for ML, but isn't in it's explicit original form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following techniques to mask sensitive data:

- [Substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher) -  any character of plain text from the given fixed set of characters is substituted by some other character from the same set depending on a key.
- Tokenization masking - mask source string data based on criteria that you specify in an algorithm.
- [Principal Components Analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or other dimension-reducing techniques - combine several features and then carry out ML training only on the resulting PCA vectors.
- Data Coarsening - decrease the precision or granularity of data to make it more difficult to identify sensitive data within the dataset.

Also, read  [Data Masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_masking) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

[Differential privacy](https://github.com/IBM/differential-privacy-library/blob/master/notebooks/pipeline.ipynb). Where you can inject targeted noise anonymise the data, but you can still make inference.